# Observable badge events using merit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observable, merit-gem

I have an issue with the merit gem that seems too obvious/easy, but struggled to figure it out.

I am using the [sample observable class](https://github.com/tute/merit#getting-notifications) and it works fine for points.  Every point change, the registered observer receives the update.  However, for badges no such update occurs.

How I am assigning the badge to the user **MIGHT** be the reason but I am uncertain why.  Again using an [example from the wiki](https://github.com/tute/merit/issues/61#issuecomment-13992156), I am looking at the total points for the user and creating the appropriate badge for that user using the `add_badge` method.  This works fine.  That is, points are being tallied as expected, badges are being created as expected, and the user's points and badges are correct.

The issue is that the observable class does not receive any update / event for these badge assignments.  I was expecting each `add_badge` to generate the notification.

What are some reasons why the badge addition is not being observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Observers are notified when the reputation (points, ranking or badges) are granted through the rules defined in `app/models/merit`. The [`Judge` object takes care of this](https://github.com/tute/merit/blob/master/lib/merit/judge.rb#L43-L47).

When you grant reputation "by hand" (calling `add_badge`) you need to call the observer manually, as in that sample code from `Judge`.

Comment: This sounds like it's better to use the `Merit::BadgeRules` rather than adding a badge manually. For example, `add_badge` does not check for multiple badges either. But, is there a way to access the controller context, for example `request.format`, from `Merit::BadgeRules`?

Comment: `Merit::BadgeRules` is better than lower level `add_badges` indeed. It does not have access to controller context. I'd like to discuss a refactor where we add that!